# There is any way to change the Logger name path

Tags: java, logging

I'm using the Java Logger class and want to know if you can automatically rename files as output the generated class.

```
static Logger logger = new Log("C:\\Trace");
static FileHandler fh;

public Log(String path) throws SecurityException, IOException{
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        fh = new FileHandler(path+ ".log", 1024 * 1024 * 5, 5, true);//5 Logs of 5Mb
        logger.addHandler(fh);
}
```

The output log is like this (Trace.log.0) and i want like Traza.0.log or something like this.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the generation number in your file pattern.  From the [j.u.l.FileHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) documentation:

> If no "%g" field has been specified and the file count is greater than one, then the generation number will be added to the end of the generated filename, after a dot.

Comment: Thanks!! this is great, now my problem is with the damm it.lck

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730890/why-is-a-lck-file-created-and-not-deleted-by-java-logging/20005326#20005326